# Solo me aparece un producto en el archivo FPDF como hago para que aparezcan todos?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, fpdf

Tengo una pagina de ventas para un proyecto y tengo que pasar los datos del carrito a una factura, tengo las tablas productos y carrito, y en el carrito se guardan las id´s de los productos que se compraron.

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"select * from productos where idProducto = 
'".$carrito['idProducto']."'");
$tax = 0; //total tax
$amount = 0; //total amount


while($productos = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
$pdf->Cell(130  ,5,$productos['nombre'],1,0);
//add thousand separator using number_format function
$pdf->Cell(25   ,5,number_format($carrito['Cantidad']),1,0);
$pdf->Cell(34   ,5,number_format($productos['precio']),1,1,'R');//end of line
//accumulate tax and amount

$amount += $productos['precio'];
 }
```

esto lo saque de un tutorial pero cuando lo ejecuto solo me aparece uno de los productos y quiero que me salgan todos, la verdad no entiendo muy bien sql, ayuda D:

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas indicar la posicion Y de escritura de la celda actual:

```
$fila = 5;
while($productos = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
 $pdf -> SetY($fila);  
 $pdf->Cell(130  ,5,$productos['nombre'],1,0);
 //add thousand separator using number_format function
 $pdf->Cell(25   ,5,number_format($carrito['Cantidad']),1,0);
 $pdf->Cell(34   ,5,number_format($productos['precio']),1,1,'R');//end of line
 //accumulate tax and amount

 $amount += $productos['precio'];
 $fila++;
}
```

Saludos!